# Adding a validator according to the operator used in react-querybuilder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, query-builder

I can add validators to fields. But I want that validator to be active only when I use the like operator.

In this example, if I used the like or unlike operators in the phoneNumber field, I expect it to be invalid since I did not use the % sign. If I used the or = operator, I should not be able to use the % sign.

How can I set this depending on the operator used?

NOTE: Also defaultValidator is not working. I think it's because I use this "import { QueryBuilderAntD } from '@react-querybuilder/antd';" . I am not sure

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Button, Modal, Row} from "antd";
import {formatMessage} from "umi";
import {CloseCircleOutlined, SelectOutlined} from "@ant-design/icons";
import TextArea from "antd/es/input/TextArea";
import {QueryBuilder, defaultValidator, formatQuery, parseSQL} from "react-querybuilder";
import 'react-querybuilder/dist/query-builder.css';
import {QueryBuilderAntD} from "@react-querybuilder/antd";

const options = [
    { name: '=', label: '=' },
    { name: '!=', label: '!=' },
    { name: 'like', label: 'like' },
    { name: 'notLike', label: 'not like' },
];

const fields = [
    {name: 'phoneNumber', validator: ({ value }) => /^(%)[0-9]*$/.test(value) , label: formatMessage({id: 'label.phoneNumber'}), operators: options},
    {name: 'passportNumber', label: formatMessage({id: 'label.passportNumber'}), operators: options, inputType: 'number'},
];

const initialQuery = {
    combinator: 'and',
    rules: [
        {
            field: 'phoneNumber',
            value: '7788',
            operator: 'notLike',
        },
        {
            combinator: 'and',
            rules: [
                {
                    field: 'passportNumber',
                    value: '3334445566',
                    operator: '=',
                },
                {
                    field: 'phoneNumber',
                    value: '%6665544',
                    operator: 'like',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            combinator: 'or',
            rules: [
                {
                    field: 'phoneNumber',
                    value: '3334445566',
                    operator: '=',
                },
            ],
        },
    ]
};

const Panel = (props) => {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState(initialQuery)
    const [queryText, setQueryText] = useState(null)

    useEffect(()=>{
        let text = formatQuery(query, 'sql')
        setQueryText(text === "(1 = 1)" ? "" : text)
    },[query]);

    useEffect(()=> {
        if (props.filterValue){
            let sorgu = parseSQL(props.filterValue)
            setQuery(sorgu)
        }
    }, [props.filterValue]);

    const onModalSelectBtnClick = () => {
        if (props.callValue) {
            props.callValue(query);
        }
        props.closeModal();
    };

    const onModalCancelBtnClick = () => {
        props.closeModal();
    };

    const clearQuery = () => {
        setQuery(initialQuery)
    };

    const selectQuery = () => {
        let text = formatQuery(query, 'sql')

        props.callValue(text === "(1 = 1)" ? null : text)
        props.closeModal();
    };

    return (
        <Modal
            title={formatMessage({id: 'label.LEXP_CDR'})}
            visible={props.visibleCallModal}
            onCancel={onModalCancelBtnClick}
            destroyOnClose={true}
            width="35%"
            style={{top: '5%'}}
            footer={[
                <Button type="primary" onClick={clearQuery} style={{marginRight: '362px'}}>
                    {formatMessage({id: 'button.clear'})}
                </Button>,
                <Button type="primary" onClick={selectQuery} icon={<SelectOutlined/>}>
                    {formatMessage({id: 'button.select'})}
                </Button>,
                <Button type="primary" onClick={onModalCancelBtnClick} icon={<CloseCircleOutlined/>}>
                    {formatMessage({id: 'button.cancel'})}
                </Button>
            ]}>
            <div>

                <QueryBuilderAntD>
                    <QueryBuilder
                        fields={fields}
                        query={query}
                        onQueryChange={q => setQuery(q)}
                        validator={defaultValidator}
                    />
                </QueryBuilderAntD>

                <Row gutter={3}>
                    <TextArea name="query" value={queryText}/>
                </Row>

            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
};


export default Panel;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't destructure the value here "validator: ({ value })"
and just pass the whole object as a operator, like that "validator: (query)",
then you can access your operator like query.operator and you can use it for conditional validation based on the operator.
It worked for me when I used the validator.